# Cuda matrix multiplication gives wrong answer

Tags: c++, cuda, matrix-multiplication

**Update!**

My current code doesn't check for out of bounds memory access. When I run the cuda memcheck, it says memory access is bad even for matrices of just 2 by 2! I'm accessing memory where I shouldn't somehow and that's the problem!

To check for out of bounds memory access, run **cuda-memcheck ./(insert executable here)**

Shown below is my code for the matrix multiplication itself:

```
dim3 block(32,32);
dim3 grid( (n+31)/32, (n+31)/32 );
matrixMul<<<grid,block>>>(d_C, d_A, d_B, n, k);
```

kA and kB are matrices with values in them (they're all 2's to make it easier).

m, n, k are all the same number for my square matrices

kC is the matrix to store the answer.

```
#ifndef _MATRIXMUL_KERNEL_H_
#define _MATRIXMUL_KERNEL_H_

#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void matrixMul(float *kC, float *kA, float *kB, int n, int k)
{

    int tx = blockIdx.x * 32 + threadIdx.x;
    int ty = blockIdx.y * 32 + threadIdx.y;
    float value = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        float elementA=kA[ty*n+i];
        float elementB=kB[i*k+tx];
        value += elementA*elementB;
    }

    kC[ty*n+tx] = value;
}

#endif // #ifndef _MATRIXMUL_KERNEL_H_
```

Comment: Am I just running out of memory or something?

Comment: Where is the definition of the variable `value` ?  Are you initializing it to zero before the for loop?  This code doesn't look like it would compile.

Comment: @Robert Crovella my bad, I wrote the wrong variable name when I moved the code. It should be "float value" and not "float storage." I have "float value" in my program though. Do you think it might be my memory if it works all the way up to 10x10's? After 10x10's the values double for some rows of the matrix or sometimes something else...

Comment: This kernel has no thread checks like `if ((ty < n) && (tx < k)){`.  So you should show your kernel invocation as well, and probably the data copy portion of the host code as well.

Comment: @Robert Crovella I updated the code to show everything.

Comment: I've updated the code on the post. Can someone help please? I still can't get past 10x10 matrices, and I have no idea why.

Comment: I don't see where you have updated the posting to show the kernel invocation, that is where you are calling the kernel from host code.

Comment: @Robert Crovella I changed things now again. I did post the kernel (and all my code for the function), but it made everything messy so I shorted it. Now, I show the kernel invocation.

Comment: You need to add the thread check to the kernel like I suggested, otherwise threads outside the valid array array will corrupt your results.  Things work for multiples of 32x32 because there are no invalid threads.  In that case you're launch exactly the required number of threads.  But in other cases you are launching extra threads.

Comment: @Robert Crovella do you mind saying more about how your thread check system works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on how you are defining the grid of threads, you should add a thread check to the kernel code like this:

```
#ifndef _MATRIXMUL_KERNEL_H_
#define _MATRIXMUL_KERNEL_H_

#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void matrixMul(float *kC, float *kA, float *kB, int n, int k)
{

    int tx = blockIdx.x * 32 + threadIdx.x;
    int ty = blockIdx.y * 32 + threadIdx.y;

    if ((ty < n) && (tx < n)) { // add this line
      float value = 0;

      for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
        float elementA=kA[ty*n+i];
        float elementB=kB[i*k+tx];
        value += elementA*elementB;
      }

      kC[ty*n+tx] = value;
    }  //  add this line
}

#endif // #ifndef _MATRIXMUL_KERNEL_H_
```

Otherwise threads outside the valid array array will corrupt your results. Things work for multiples of 32x32 because there are no invalid threads. In that case you're launching exactly the required number of threads. But in other cases you are launching extra threads.  These extra threads, if allowed to compute an invalid matrix position, will corrupt the results.

Comment: Wow, that fixed everything. I appreciate it. So basically what's happening then is that the threads are initialized based on my kernel call and run even if they're out of bounds without that if statement?

Comment: Yes, you define the size of the grid with the kernel invocation.  When the kernel launches with that grid, all of those threads will launch, and at some point, begin executing the thread code (kernel code).